# Добавление произвольного класса в цикле вывода дочерних страниц на WP

Tags: wordpress

Есть родительская страница Каталог, на ней выводятся рандомно товары. Также выводятся дочерние страницы Категории этих товаров. Когда пользователь на странице Каталог эти ссылки на дочерние страницы не активны. А если пользователь кликает на одну из ссылок, то переходит на новую страницу и нужно добавить активный класс ссылке на эту страницу. Вот код вывода этих дочерних страниц.

```
<?php $static_children = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type'=>'page', 'post__in' => array( 42, 70, 65, 67 ) ) ); ?>
                <div class="catalog__tabs">
                <?php if($static_children->have_posts()) :?>
                    <?php while($static_children->have_posts()): $static_children->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="catalog__tabs-item">
                              <?php 

    $image = get_field('tab_icon');

    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span>
</a>                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: а какая проблема вместо `<a href` написать `<a class="active" href`?

Comment: добавляет всем айтемам клас active, может можно как-то по id ловить и добавлять на соотвествуючей странице?

Comment: не понимаю сути вопроса, кому добавлять и кому не добавлять.